# Simple way to calculate point of intersection between two polygons in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, polygon

I've got two polygons defined as a list of Vectors, I've managed to write routines to transform and intersect these two polygons (seen below Frame 1). Using line-intersection I can figure out whether these collide, and have written a working Collide() function.

This is to be used in a variable step timed game, and therefore (as shown below) in Frame 1 the right polygon is not colliding, it's perfectly normal for on Frame 2 for the polygons to be right inside each other, with the right polygon having moved to the left.

My question is, what is the best way to figure out the moment of intersection? In the example, let's assume in Frame 1 the right polygon is at X = 300, Frame 2 it moved -100 and is now at 200, and that's all I know by the time Frame 2 comes about, it was at 300, now it's at 200. What I want to know is when did it actually collide, at what X value, here it was probably about 250.

[image: Polygon intersect]

I'm preferably looking for a C# source code solution to this problem.
Maybe there's a better way of approaching this for games?

Comment: I guess that one polygon is static, and the other has fixed velocity vector (vx,vy)?  How many points do you have in your polygon?

Comment: There's not a great deal, no more than 20 or so. It's going to be called on a relatively limited basis, initially it can be bounds checked to avoid heavy calculations. And I could potentially ensure the polygons are convex.

Comment: @Rob: please fix your post to clarify whether you need: **a working solution for this problem**, **a source code of working solution for this problem** , **a source code of the most primitive solution for this problem**. Your question is too broad: it's hard to tell whether you're about to write your own game or you're just a student and have no idea how to make your programming lab. Answers are absolutely different depending on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the separating axis theorem, as outlined here:

- [Metanet tutorial](http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html)
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separating_axis_theorem)

Then I would [sweep test](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3383/simple_intersection_tests_for_games.php) or use [multisampling](http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html#section5) if needed.

GMan here on StackOverflow wrote a sample implementation over at [gpwiki.org](http://www.gpwiki.org/index.php/VB%3aTutorials%3aBuilding_A_Physics_Engine%3aBasic_Intersection_Detection).

This may all be overkill for your use-case, but it handles polygons of any order. Of course, for simple bounding boxes it can be done much more efficiently through other means.

Comment: That metanet tutorial is fantastically well written. I'll look into this as a solution, thank you.

Comment: @Rob: Aye, it's good for mathematically challenged individuals like me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no mathematician either, but one possible though crude solution would be to run a mini simulation.

Let us call the moving polygon *M* and the stationary polygon *S* (though there is no requirement for *S* to actually be stationary, the approach should work just the same regardless). Let us also call the two frames you have *F1* for the earlier and *F2* for the later, as per your diagram.

If you were to translate polygon *M* back towards its position in *F1* in very small increments until such time that they are no longer intersecting, then you would have a location for *M* at which it 'just' intersects, i.e. the previous location before they stop intersecting in this simulation. The intersection in this 'just' intersecting location should be very small — small enough that you could treat it as a point. Let us call this polygon of intersection *I*.

To treat *I* as a point you could choose the vertex of it that is nearest the centre point of *M* in *F1*: that vertex has the best chance of being outside of *S* at time of collision. (There are lots of other possibilities for interpreting *I* as a point that you could experiment with too that may have better results.)

Obviously this approach has some drawbacks:

- The simulation will be slower for greater speeds of *M* as the distance between its locations in *F1* and *F2* will be greater, more simulation steps will need to be run. (You could address this by having a fixed number of simulation cycles irrespective of speed of *M* but that would mean the accuracy of the result would be different for faster and slower moving bodies.)
- The 'step' size in the simulation will have to be sufficiently small to get the accuracy you require but smaller step sizes will obviously have a larger calculation cost.

Personally, without the necessary mathematical intuition, I would go with this simple approach first and try to find a mathematical solution as an optimization later.

Comment: This is actually similar to my current solution. I 'backtrack' along the velocity vector for the polygon M, and find the point at which the polygons did not intersect. There are some issues with this approach, but it does work. And there are things I can do to speed it up, such as subdivision along the vector.

Comment: @Rob: thinking about it some more, you could perform a binary search. Try half way back and see whether it intersects or not. If it does you need only search the earlier half (towards F1) , if not only the later half (towards F2). Rinse, repeat.

Comment: It's a good idea, but the drawback is really fast objects. Many games actually do something similar, but they do it before they hit. If you have an object moving really fast it may actually move through objects in a single timestep, naïve detection code (for example some of mine, :D) wouldn't cope with this. The hit would never be registered. Of course, it all depends on the specific game.

Comment: @paul That what I was talking about with subdivision :) Maybe that was the wrong terminology.

Comment: @Skurmedel Yep, you would also need to do this forward along the velocity vector at a step interval to ensure it didn't zip right through the object, then backtrace. All these things add extra calculations :(

Comment: @Skurmedel, is this not just a problem of choosing a sufficiently small timestep for the (known) speed of objects that one has in one's game? OP is suggesting that he's nailed the collision detection but is unable to (elegantly) identify the collision *point*.

Comment: @Paul: Sure, if you can do that it's good. But it would put certain limitations on stuff.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the ability to determine whether the two polygons overlap, one idea might be to use a modified binary search to detect where the two hit.  Start by subdividing the time interval in half and seeing if the two polygons intersected at the midpoint.  If so, recursively search the first half of the range; if not, search the second half.  If you specify some tolerance level at which you no longer care about small distances (for example, at the level of a pixel), then the runtime of this approach is O(log D / K), where D is the distance between the polygons and K is the cutoff threshold.  If you know what point is going to ultimately enter the second polygon, you should be able to detect the collision very quickly this way.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

For a rather generic solution, and assuming ...

1. no polygons are intersecting at time = 0
2. at least one polygon is intersecting another polygon at time = t
3. and you're happy to use a C# clipping library (eg [Clipper](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php))

then use a binary approach to deriving the time of intersection by...

```
double tInterval = t;
double tCurrent = 0;
int direction = +1;
while (tInterval > MinInterval)
{
  tInterval = tInterval/2;
  tCurrent += (tInterval * direction);
  MovePolygons(tCurrent);
  if (PolygonsIntersect) 
    direction = +1;
  else 
    direction = -1;         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well - you may see that it's allways a point of one of the polygons that hits the side of the other first (or another point - but thats after all almost the same) - a possible solution would be to calculate the distance of the points from the other lines in the move-direction. But I think this would end beeing rather slow.

I guess normaly the distances between frames are so small that it's not importand to really know excactly where it hit first - some small intersections will not be visible and after all the things will rebound or explode anyway - don't they? :)

Comment: What if polygon A is Mario, and polygon B is a block he's jumping up and down on (for arguments sake). As he falls and lands in the block, you need to be able to "push him out", you need to know where the top line of the block is relative to where he hit it.

Comment: sure but Mario used to be a rectangle with sides parallel to the screen-sides and so was the block - so no big brainer here. And the modern marios have a lot of clipping problems. Hittest are IMHO never really on the point but allways on some hit-boxes. Maybe this will change but ATM you will trade details with speed and use the pragmatic approach...

Comment: Mario was just a simple example, imagine he has two pointy feet that aren't flat, and is standing on a slope or between two spikes :)

Comment: all I want to say is: I think you have to find a balance for hit-box size and performance. Really calculating the excact point of intersection on complex models is just performance-overkill (just look at raytracing - maybe this *will* be comming after all but right now you can play wolfenstein-raytrace only on mainframes ;) )